# Showing a set G is closed under addition

Tags: abstract-algebra

For $a\in\Bbb{R}$, let $$G=a\Bbb{Z}=\{am|m\in\Bbb{Z}\}$$
How do I show that $G$ is closed addition, i.e., $a,b\in G\Rightarrow a+b\in G$ 
and that $(G,+)$ is a group?

Comment: Just try it... you take two elements from $G$ and try to show that their sum is still in $G$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It's somewhat confusing that you used $a$ for the generator of $G$ and also as a generic element of $G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closure:

If $b,c\in G$ then $b=am$ and $ c=an$, so $b+c=a(m+n)\in G$.

(Follows from closure of $\mathbb Z$ under addition.)

Identity:

$0=a0\in a\mathbb Z$

Inverse:

if $b=ma$ then $-b=(-m)a\in C$

Associative:  follows from associativity of addition in $\mathbb Z$.